# Prevent from calling main() recursively in C++

Tags: c++, c, program-entry-point

I have a similar code to the following:

```
int main()
{
    'some
     code'
     motors();
}

int motors()
{
     if (condition)
     {
          'some
           code'
           main();
     }
     else if (condition)
     {
          'some
           code'
           main();
     }
     else
     {
           main();
     }
}
```

What could I do to prevent from calling main over and over? Could I make another function with main's code in it?

Comment: "What could I do to prevent from calling main over and over?" Just do not call it from your functions.

Comment: calling main from anywhere is an undefined bahavior

Comment: I thought about that but I need to refresh values that are then used in the motors function. I NEED to go back and check main. I was asking if I could make another function to check those values, or would that be the same thing?

Comment: where is the `motors()` function called from ?

Comment: @juanchopanza That is not how I meant it.

Comment: @SirDarius It's called at the end of main()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `main` is undefined behavior in C++. You can wrap all the functions originally in `main` to another function.

```
int main()
{
    wrapper();
}

void wrapper()
{
    //code originally in main
}
```

And whenever you need to call `main`, call this wrapper instead.

```
int motors()
{
     if (condition)
     {
         wrapper();
     }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. A follow-up question: when motors() calls wrapper() and wrapper() finishes, does the code continue from the last position in motors() or does motors() restart?

Comment: The normal recursion rule applies. If you put all the code originally in `main` to this wrapper function, it must call the function `motor` somewhere directly or indirectly. You need to be sure this is what you want to do.

Comment: Turns out calling main is not UB, but makes the program ill-formed: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68564133/3537677

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple of avoiding calling a function recursively: Don't do it! In fact, there is seldom any need to call `main` from inside a program, and I think it's generally should be avoided at all cost (except for "clever hacks" such as those used in [the IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/)).

Instead, you should use loops:

```
int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        some_code_that_calls_motors();
    }
}
```

Then just return from the function, and the calling call-chain until you're back in `main` and the loop starts over.