# Why is calling the main function supposedly undefined behavior (UB)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I fear this is again a question about interpreting the ISO/IEC 14882 (the C++ standard) but:

Is calling `main` from the program e.g. my calling `main()` recursively from `main` not at least implementation defined behavior? (Update: I imply later ill-formed not implementation defined, also not UB, see below and answer)

6.9.3.1 [basic.start.main] states

> 3 The function main shall not be used within a program. The linkage (6.6) of main is implementation-defined...

The [consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19891183/3537677) seems to be undefined behavior (UB). The [documentation of MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=msvc-160) also points towards UB, the [one of gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Implementation.html#C_002b_002b-Implementation) also implicitly denies implementation-defined behavior. It can not be [defns.unspecified] unspecified behavior since I would interpret *shall not* as ill-formed.

However, despite the implementations, to my interpretation is should not be UB but as 4.1  [intro.compliance] states

> 1 The set of diagnosable rules consists of all syntactic and semantic rules in this document except for those
> rules containing an explicit notation that “no diagnostic is required” or which are described as resulting in
> “undefined behavior”.
> ...
> (2.2) — If a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule or an occurrence of a construct described in
> this document as “conditionally-supported” when the implementation does not support that construct,
> a conforming implementation shall issue at least one diagnostic message.

For me the reasoning seems clear

---

### tl;dr

1. calling main implies the program contains a violation of the rule of [basic.start.main]
2. [basic.start.main] does not state calling/use is UB or a diagnostic is not required
3. 1. is an element of "diagnosable rules" as per [intro.compliance]
4. [intro.compliance] 2.2 states violation of any diagnoseable rule must be issued at least one diagnostic message
5. Since 3. and 4. the usage of main shall issue at least one diagnostic message
6. Since 5. 1. is not UB
7. Since neither gcc,MSVC or clang issue an error or warning but compile, all major implementations are not compliant

Of course since 7. I feel again in the Don Quixote scenario i.e. being wrong, so I would appreciate if someone could enlighten me about my mistake. Otherwise, there are standard defects, aren't there?

Comment: As an aside, do you know why (or care) `main` shall not be called?

Comment: Some one did in the code if his question, and I was wondering if this also could be the cause of his problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68561290/3537677
And the reason why its forbidden by the standard is clear, since there is stuff to be done before main can actually execute that should be done exactly once and by the thread the OS knows, like dynamic initalization of global i.e. static data, constructors of global objects, runtime house keeping and so on.

Comment: From what I know, it is because some versions of C++ generated static initialization and teardown code within the body of `main`, and the hosting environment directly loads the `main` symbol and runs it.

Comment: Yes, but when they do that, they have to issue an diagnostic message i.e. warning/error, when compiling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your analysis is correct: calls to `main` are ill-formed.

You have to pass the `-pedantic` flag to make GCC and Clang conform. In that case, Clang says

```
warning: ISO C++ does not allow 'main' to be used by a program [-Wmain]
```

and GCC says

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids taking address of function '::main' [-Wpedantic]
```

But they allow calls to `main` as an extension. The standard permits such an extension, since it doesn't change the meaning of any conforming programs.

Comment: So MSVC would at least be non compliant since they don't say anything like this in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/nonstandard-behavior?view=msvc-160 or did I miss a pendantic flag for them as well? Isn't the default behaviour i.e. the existence of such a flag, a compliance issue? I.e. doesn't the standard imply that be default the implementation has to be compliant? At least the need of the flag should be listed in non compliant behavior

Comment: Ah I guess I have to read that extension thing. That answers my question I guess. Thank you

Comment: @Superlokkus not really, at least practically. A lot of non-standard extensions are built into compilers and nonobody seems to think that makes them non-compliant. Admittedly, among those extensions, the one allowing to call `main` is the least useful, at least to me.

Comment: @SergeyA ridiculously easy to work around, at any rate.

Comment: I think you meant "doesn't change the meaning of any *well-formed* program". C++ (as of the 2017 standard) doesn't seem to define the term "conforming program". (C does, but the definition is absurdly lax.)