# Why the count in my main is not updated when i entered new patient info?

Tags: c++

Why the `count` in my main is not updated when I entered new patient info? I don't know why for case 2 in my add function, the `count` in main will never increase. It remains at 20 only(same with my input text) even after I type in new patient info.
Here is my code:

```cpp
struct PATIENT
{
    string id;
    string name;
    string age;
    string address;
    string doc;
    string diagnosis;
    string status;
    string date;
};

struct LIST
{
    PATIENT patient[100];
};

void get_data(LIST* p, int* count);
void add(LIST* p, int* count);

int main()
{
    LIST p;
    int count, choice;
    get_data(&p, &count);
    cout << "The count is: " << count;
    add(&p, &count);
}

void get_data(LIST* p, int* count)
{
    int num = 0;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("input.txt");

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Error to open an input file\n";
        exit(0);
    }

    else
    {

        while (num < 100 && !inFile.eof())
        {
            getline(inFile, p->patient[num].id);
            getline(inFile, p->patient[num].name);
            getline(inFile, p->patient[num].age);
            getline(inFile, p->patient[num].address);
            getline(inFile, p->patient[num].doc);
            getline(inFile, p->patient[num].diagnosis);
            getline(inFile, p->patient[num].status);
            getline(inFile, p->patient[num].date);
            num++;
        }
    }

    *count = num;

    inFile.close();
}

void add(LIST* p, int* count)
{
    system("cls");
    int patientSelect = 2;
    switch (patientSelect)
    {
    case 1: cout << "Existing patient";
        break;
    case 2:system("cls");
        cout << "\t\t\t\tNew patient" << endl;
        cout << "\t\t\t\t===========" << endl;
        cout << "Enter patient ID: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, p->patient[*count].id);
        cout << "Enter patient name: ";
        getline(cin, p->patient[*count].name);
        cout << "Enter age: ";
        cin >> p->patient[*count].age;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Enter address: ";
        getline(cin, p->patient[*count].address);
        cout << "Enter attending doctor's name: ";
        getline(cin, p->patient[*count].doc);
        cout << "Enter diagnosis: ";
        getline(cin, p->patient[*count].diagnosis);
        cout << "Enter patient status: ";
        getline(cin, p->patient[*count].status);
        cout << "Enter consultation date: ";
        getline(cin, p->patient[*count].date);
        *count++;
        system("PAUSE"); system("cls"); main();
        break;
    case 3: system("cls"); main();
    default:cin.clear(); cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); cout << "Invalid input, please try again..." << endl;
        system("PAUSE"); system("cls");
    }
}
```

My output in main:
The count is 20(after add function)

Comment: You're incrementing `count` inside `add`, now where are you calling `add` in your code?

Comment: Could you add a line like `std::cout << "Final count is " << count << ".\n";` to demonstrate that `count` is not updated?

Comment: @enzo i have eddited my code , i call it under my get_data function

Comment: @JaMiT i have editted and added in the main

Comment: Calling `main` has undefined behaviour. You're not allowed to do that.

Comment: @YewKang In order to see if the `count` in `main()` has been updated, you *also* need an output line after the call to `add()`. If you don't hit the line after `add()` then you are not looking at the same `count`. (Each invocation of a function creates its own copies of non-`static` local variables. And that's before noting that [explicitly calling `main()` makes your program ill-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68564133/why-is-calling-the-main-function-supposedly-undefined-behavior-ub).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is c++ operator precedence. See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Change `*count++` to `(*count)++`. If you don't do this, your code is equivalent to `*(count++)`, which is valid c++, but it just does nothing...

But I would rather pass an int reference to the functions, and not a pointer to int. This makes coding simpler and less error prone.

Another problem is that you call `main` again from inside `add`. But in `main` you start from scratch: read the data, etc. All you changes will always be overwritten. Please consider that:

```
void setup(LIST& p, int& count) {
    get_data(&p, &count);
}

void update(LIST& p, int& count) {
    while (true) {
      cout << "Command (0:exit, 2:add, etc.): "; 
      int choice=0;
      cin >> choice;
      if (choice==0) {
        break;
      }  
      cout << "The count is: " << count;
      add(&p, &count);   /// <= I would also pass choice here as argument and use it instead of patientSelect, but please check your business logic. 
   }
}

int main()
{
    LIST p;
    int count=0;
    setup(p, count);
    update(p, count);
}
```

And of course, do NOT call `main` from anywhere any more. Remove all those calls to `main`.

Comment: i have tried it out but it still work the same

Comment: even use the pass by reference also did not work...

Comment: Yes... because you also call `main` again. This makes no sense. If you restart `main`, you start from scratch: all changes are over written!

Comment: I will update my answer with a proposed solution.